# DPRP is disabled for this merchant sandbox account

Tags: paypal

I created new sandbox account for buyer and tried `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` as `Method`.

it worked fine and created new recurring profile first time.

but now suddenly I am getting below Error:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-05-18T21:11:41Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 1a8fea918c26d
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 98.0
    [BUILD] => 16660223
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11586
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled for this merchant.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

it is currently sandbox.

please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

DPRP = Direct Payment Recurring Payments

The DoDirectPayment API is enabled with Website Payments Pro 3.0, and that's what is used when creating recurring profiles with credit cards directly.

You need to get Website Payments Pro 3.0 activated on the sandbox account in order to run these transactions.

Did you create a new business sandbox account recently?  New ones should have this enabled by default.  If not, you can send a message to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) and they can enable it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I created new business sandbox accound, and its working.

Comment: @RahulKaushik so you have to use a different email and create an entirely new paypal account?  did you have to pay to make it a business account?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Website Payments Pro for the sandbox business account. In the current interface (2018) view this page:

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Find your Business account, expand it and click Profile. Under 'Account Type' there should be a link to 'Upgrade to Pro'.